# Difference in using * in Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

What is the difference between `(*current = *current->next)`and `(current = current->next)`?
My code is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {

        ListNode* current = head;
        while(current!=NULL)
        {
            while (current->next!=NULL && current->val==current->next->val)
                *current = *current->next;
            current = current->next;
        }
        return head;
    }
};
```

Comment: do you understand the difference between `*p = *q` and `p = q` where `p` and `q` are pointers?

Comment: `current = current->next` is the one you want.  The other one is actually copying data around and overwriting stuff - not what you want.

Comment: The `*` operator before a pointer, dereferences the pointer, returns the value at the location pointed to by the pointer.  Without the `*` operator, only the pointer *contents* are copied (not the thing pointed to by the pointer).

Comment: `*current = *current->next;` seems like it will cause a memory leak.

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing the concept!

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
*current = *current->next;
```

the object of the type `ListNode` pointed to by the pointer `current->next` is assigned to the object of the same type pointed to by the pointer `current`.

In this statement

```
current = current->next;
```

the value of the pointer `current->next` is assigned to the pointer `current`.

As for the function itself then it should be defined at least the following way if its purpose is deleting adjacent nodes with duplicated values.

```
ListNode * deleteDuplicates( ListNode *head ) 
{
    for ( ListNode *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        while ( current->next != NULL && current->val == current->next->val )
        {
            ListNode *tmp = current->next;
            current->next = current->next->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Also it seems the function could be declared as a static member function like

```
static ListNode * deleteDuplicates( ListNode *head )
{
    //...
}
```

And instead of the null pointer constant `NULL` you should use the null pointer literal `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

The dereference operator `*` gets the value that the pointer is *pointing to*.

The statement

```
*current = *current->next;
```

assigns from the object that `current->next` is pointing to, to the object that `current` is pointing to.

Now when you don't use the dereference operator:

```
current = current->next;
```

you assign the *pointers*, not the objects they point to.

After this assignment then you have two pointers both pointing to the same object.

---

It might be easier to understand if we draw it out using pen and paper. Draw an object using a rectangle, and label it appropriately. Then draw another rectangle and connect it to the first using an arrow.

This second rectangle is *pointing* to the first rectangle, just like a pointer does in C++.

By using the dereference operator `*` you follow the arrow to the first rectangle.

So lets say we have the object `node`:

```
+------+
| node |
+------+
```

Then we create a pointer `current` that points to `node`:

```
+---------+     +------+
| current | --> | node |
+---------+     +------+
```

When you use `current` you get the pointer itself. When you use `*current` you follow the arrow and get `node`.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick lesson in pointers

This declares a pointer variable:

```
ListNode* current;
```

This declares a ListNode variable:

```
ListNode node;
```

This sets the pointer to *point at* `node`:

```
current = &node;
```

This `*` operator *dereferences* `current` and the following two lines mean exactly the same thing:

```
std::cout << *current << '\n';
std::cout << node << '\n';
```

So when you write `*current` that is whatever `current` is pointing at, which is a `ListNode`.